# How do you turn off setDragImage

Tags: javascript

just as it states. how do you disable the drag image. I have a floating panel and the drag image looks very bad. no-jquery please.

Comment: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) example please.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DragDrop/DataTransfer#setDragImage.28.29):

> If the node is an HTML `img` element, an HTML `canvas` element or a XUL `image` element, the image data is used. Otherwise, `image` should be a visible node and the drag image will be created from this.

From this it would follow that to "turn off" the drag image you should just pass an empty (but visibile) element to `setDragImage`. How about this:

```
// create an empty <span>
var dragImgEl = document.createElement('span');

// set its style so it'll be effectively (but not technically) invisible and
// won't change document flow
dragImgEl.setAttribute('style',
  'position: absolute; display: block; top: 0; left: 0; width: 0; height: 0;' );

// add it to the document
document.body.appendChild(dragImgEl);

// your DataTransfer code here--assume we put it in a variable called 'dt'

dt.setDragImage(dragImgEl, 0, 0);
```

If an empty `<span>` doesn't work for some reason you could always use `<img src="blank.png"/>` where `blank.png` is a transparent 1-pixel PNG. Hope that helps!

Comment: Nicely done!  Saved me a headache or two.  Too bad the OP didn't accept this as the answer....

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wRnSnfiUI54

Comment: You could use data URL to create transparent pixel on-the-fly:

`var img = document.createElement('img'); img.src = 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==';`

Comment: This comment should be broken out into a separate, super-upvoted answer.

Comment: This does not look like working for me in current Firefox.

Answer (score 24):

**Set the ghost image to a transparent 1x1px gif using data string**

Took inspiration from a comment in the thread, however the image they put in their comment didn't work so I had to scour around for this one.

This solves my issue in all browsers.

**Updated Nov 10th, 2022**

Changed to add support for Safari by preloading the image.

```
//Preload the image
var img = document.createElement("img");   
img.src = "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7";

element.addEventListener('dragstart', function(event) {
  event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(img, 0, 0);
}, false);
```

Comment: This didn't work for me in Safari. Found how to improve it a bit in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/22610927/467851

Comment: @AndreyStukalin updated the answer to better support browsers by preloading

Answer (score 3):

Set it to an un-sourced image:

```
event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(document.createElement('img'), 0, 0);
```

Comment: In Chrome this will present a broken image icon next to the cursor.