# how to hide drag image in html website

Tags: image, drag-and-drop, html5-canvas

I'm implementing some drag/drop functionality from a button onto a canvas on my html5 site. When the drag operation is over the canvas, I start drawing custom shapes under the cursor. However, by default the button's image is included in the drag process thereby overlaying my canvas drawings. Is there any way to hide the default drag image? It seems that one can call `setDragImage` but that's not supported in IE9 and calling `setDragImage(null, 0, 0)` doesn't work in Chrome either. What are my options?

edit: to be clear, I'd like to hide the ghost image that is created with native drag/drop

Comment: Exact duplicate of [How do you turn off setDragImage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680285/how-do-you-turn-off-setdragimage)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you turn off setDragImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680285/how-do-you-turn-off-setdragimage)