# Javascript HTML5 Drag events not firing on Safari (Mac), dragging does not work

Tags: javascript, html, safari

In a react application, we design a custom dragging function. While working on Firefox and Chrome, it does not work on Safari.

Immediately after the dragstart event, the dragend event fires, ondrag never fires. Dragstart looks like the code below. We need to show no drag image in this case.

```
onDragStart={e => {
               e.stopPropagation()
               e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', 'anything')
               let pic = new Image()
               pic.style.visibility = 'hidden'
               e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(pic, 0, 0)
               e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'default'
               if (this.state.hover) {
                 this.calcBoxSizes(true)
               }
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding an empty GIF as the image source for the setDragImage fixed the issue. We just add: 
**pic.src = "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7"**

```
onDragStart={e => {
               //console.log('ondragstart')
               e.stopPropagation()
               e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', 'anything')
               let pic = new Image()
               pic.src = "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" //transparent gif, resolves issue with Safari that otherwise does not allow dragging
               pic.style.visibility = 'hidden'
               e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(pic, 0, 0)
               e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'default'
               if (this.state.hover) {
                 this.calcBoxSizes(true)
               }
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer from OP didn't work for me as is. Found the solution [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22610927/467851). Basically what needs to be done is to move the image creation out of the event handler. Something like this:

```
var img = document.createElement("img");   
img.src = "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7";

dragMe.addEventListener('dragstart', function(e)
{
    e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(img, 0, 0);
}, false);
```

This is obviously not React, but I guess the idea is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Everything worked perfectly on Chromium-based browsers and Firefox but on Safari... it took me half of a day to figure it out.

Safari seems to be silently sending `dragend` event if there is an issue with setting drag image. To make it work I needed to have an **image element already in DOM tree**.

```html
<style>
    .dropContainer {
        position: relative;
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
        background-color: lightgray;
        border: solid 1px black;
        user-select: none;
        -webkit-user-drop: element;
    }
    .draggableElement {
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        margin: 10px;
        position: relative;
        border: solid 1px black;
        user-select: none;
        -webkit-user-drag: element;
    }

    .draggableElement > img {
        pointer-events: none;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <div
        class="dropContainer"
        ondragover="handleDragOver(event)"
        ondrop="handleDrop(event)"
    >
        <div
            class="draggableElement"
            draggable="true"
            ondragstart="handleDragStart(event)"
            ondragend="handleDragEnd(event)">
                <img
                    id="markerIcon"
                    src="https://icons.veryicon.com/32/System/Small%20%26%20Flat/map%20marker.png"
                />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    function isSafari() {
        const agent = navigator.userAgent;

        return agent.indexOf("Chrome") === -1 && agent.indexOf("Safari") > -1;
    }

    function getIconElement() {
        if (isSafari()) {
            return document.getElementById("markerIcon");
        }

        const image = new Image();
        image.src = "https://icons.veryicon.com/32/System/Small%20%26%20Flat/map%20marker.png";

        return image;
    }

    function handleDragStart(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(getIconElement(), 14.5, 35);
        event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "move";

        console.log("dragstart", event);
    }

    function handleDragEnd(event) {
        console.log("dragend", event);
    }

    function handleDragOver(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    function handleDrop(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem occur on Safari, but the cause of the problem was that I had a hidden div over the top of my page which was hidden using `visibility:hidden`

This didn't cause any problems in Chrome or Firefox, but it blocked any drag and drop functionality on the page in Safari

I changed the css for hiding the div to `display:none` , and drag and drop started working in Safari again